# magento2 : copy sales_order table custom data to sales_order_grid

Tags: magento2, database

i want to add **custome data** when data adds in **sales_order** automatically it copied into  **sales_order_grid**
i have **same** name **column** in **both** **table**

Comment: custom data or customer data?

Comment: custom field data

Answer (score 5):

Try following way:

**VendorName/ModuleName/etc/di.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <virtualType name="Magento\Sales\Model\ResourceModel\Order\Grid" type="Magento\Sales\Model\ResourceModel\Grid">
        <arguments>
            <argument name="columns" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="custom_column_name" xsi:type="string">sales_order.custom_column_name</item>
            </argument>
        </arguments>
    </virtualType>
</config>
```

Clear cache and have to di compile.

Comment: if    want to implement virtual  column on grid column?

Comment: not virtual i want to put data in sales_order_grid table as data enters in sales_order
programatically

Comment: just adding this code to di file ..how it works?

Comment: as i place order i add extra data to sales_order table i just want to add those data to sales_order_grid automatically

Comment: Now you just added above di.xml, then automatically save your sales_order table column data to sales_order_grid column.

Comment: This adds column data after the code is added, the column for previous orders remains empty.